# Чтение/запись файла без использования I/O

Tags: lua, файлы

Здравствуйте, интересует такой вопрос - в проекте как я понял не используется I/O, каким образом мне выполнить чтение запись файла без использования I/O?

Comment: lua использует возможности написанные на языке СИ, при работе с файлами вы получаете косвенный доступ к I/O системе. так что получается I/O система все таки используется в lua

Comment: Выполнить I/O-операции без использования I/O? Вас ничего не смущает?

Comment: А как же file:read (···), file:write (···) или это тожу io?
Просто io.opеn и тд в проекте не работают (может можно этот io как то подключить?)

Comment: просто человека явно смущает что он не видит в кодах строки следующего характера

    require "io"

Comment: Просто код

    if(type(io) ~= "table") then
        print("I/O not available :(");
    else
        print("We have I/O!");
    end

выдает I/O not available :(, а require "io" пишет что файл io.lua не найден.

Comment: все правильно такого файла нет. просто система ввода вывода уже включена по умолчанию. просто пишите свои обращения к файловой системе и все (не надо писать require "io").

Comment: вот например пример обращения к файловой системе, там используется класс-таблица io которая доступна по умолчанию без подключения дополнительных модулей: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889589/create-a-new-file-in-lua-luafilesystem

вот мой пример

    $ lua
    Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
    > print(type(io))
    table
    >

хотя возможно у вас старая версия луа

Answer (score 2):

вот пример записи без встроенного i/o в lua (linux)

```
os.execute("touch /tmp/myfile")
os.execute("echo 123 > /tmp/myfile")
```